# Understand the neighbour check in a Matrix

Tags: python

I found this piece of Code on stackoverflow and trying to use it for my own code but I have to understand what every statement is doing. I know now **thanks to jonrshape** that this code should check all surround positions and if there is a neighbor 1

```
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols-1): #Loop until the second to last element.
        lives = 0
        if matrix[x][y+1] == 1:
            lives += 1
        if x == 0:  #You probably don't want to check x-1 = -1
            continue 
        if matrix[x-1][y+1] == 1:
            lives += 1
```

So I hope some could explain it step by step

So I could try to implement it without annoying you

**Edit**

I think that the first if is checking the position blow the first (x/y) but what's with neighbor on right side

Code source [Python Matrix Neighbor Checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621651/python-matrix-neighbor-checking)

**Edit2**

My Opinion what the statement is doing

```
 for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols-1):       # thats the part i would like to know how it works,what it does really
        lives = 0

        if matrix[x][y+1] == 1:

            lives += 1
                                      |0||0||0||1||0||0||0||0|...
Checking  the x coord if it is a 1 -> |1|
it increase the the O above to 1      |0|
                                      |0| 
                                      |0|
        if x == 0:  
            continue 

 Checking  the x coord if it is a O -> |0||0||0||1||0||0||0||0|
 if its a 0 than it continue to check. |0|
                                       |0|
                                       |0| 
                                       |0|
        if matrix[x-1][y+1] == 1:     # thats the second part i would like to know how it works, what it does really
            lives += 1
```

Comment: Sharing the source of the code would be a good idea

Comment: @kroolik sure I updated it

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions

Comment: @jonrsharpe I already read that, thats also the reason why  I am telling you what I understand, but I don't understand why for y in range(cols-1). Also I would like to increase 1 but instead of a 0 I have a '*' so not a number like in the code

Comment: So why don't you include that information in your question? What don't you understand about that line; it even has a comment to explain what it does? If your question is *"how can I compare to `'*'` instead of `1`?"*, can you honestly not figure out what you'd need to change?

Comment: @jonrsharpe so I updated it again and yeah I am now sure how to change it: I understand now that it does the basic things that I would like to get. So I am not sure work with it because I want to learn how this works

Answer (score 0):

The first important thing to realise about this code is the `x` and `y` on each `for` loop iteration are the *coordinates of the cell you are currently checking*. You then therefore add or subtract `1` to/from each of the coordinates to find the neighbouring cells, like so:

```
 x-1, y-1 | x-1, y | * x-1, y+1
--------------------------------
 x, y-1   | x, y   | * x, y+1
--------------------------------
 x+1, y-1 | x+1, y | x+1, y+1
```

Note that there are obvious exceptions to this:

1. You can't check `y-1` if you're on the first column (`y==0`);
2. You can't check `y+1` if you're on the last column (`y==cols-1`);
3. You can't check `x-1` if you're on the first row (`x==0`); and
4. You can't check `x+1` if you're on the last row (`x==rows-1`).

The code you have found deals with that in two slightly different ways; first, by excluding the last column from the range of `y` values:

```
for y in range(cols-1):
```

as `range` gives values *up to but not including* the `stop` argument, `y+1` will never be out of bounds. Second, by explicitly calling `continue` to skip the rest of the loop if `x == 0`:

```
 if x == 0:  
    continue
```

as `x-1` would work (giving `-1`), but this would "wrap around" to checking the last row; probably not the desired behaviour.

The second important thing to realise is that this code therefore adds `1` to `lives` for up to two neighbouring cells (right and above-right, highlighted with `*` above) for each cell in the matrix, if the neighbour contains `1`. `lives` is a **single number** - the function *doesn't alter the `matrix`* (despite your comment, it won't actually *"increase the 0 above"*). To do that, you would need to explicitly alter the values, e.g.:

```
if matrix[x][y+1] == 1:
    matrix[x][y] += 1
```

What you want will be similar, but your function should probably return *a new matrix*, where the value of each cell is the count of `'O'`s in its neighbours (i.e. an integer `0` to `8`). Alternatively, you may want to include the `'O'`s in the output matrix at the same coordinates as the input matrix.

There are broadly two ways of doing this:

- Add one to a cell for each bomb in its neighbouring cells; or
- Add one to every neighbouring cell of a bomb.

Comment: but I need to define the row and cols

Comment: so coordinates = [(x, y) for x in xrange(width) for y in xrange(height)] what do you think

Comment: @user3629826 please don't post little snippets of code for review. Opinion is largely irrelevant - *does it work?!* Consider adopting [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) - decide what you want the output of your function to be, write a test e.g. `assert function(arguments) == output` then work towards running that test without errors.

Comment: I have another idea how is it possible to use a matrix ina new def neighbor, but the matrix  is created in the def mines

Comment: is it possible to use a result from a def before?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Before what?! You can pass objects around; why don't you `return matrix` from `mines` and/or make it an argument to `neighbour`? Read [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: I add a answer I get now a error that 
IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: so you can delete my Question